# Disable the button during the initial load, enable after the submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I want to have the `btnDisableFilteredList` disabled during the initial page load.  Then I want to enabled the enable it after the `btnSearch` button is click. How do I do it using jQuery?

```html
<div class="panel panel-heading">
  <form id="frmAutoCritical">
    Search: <input type="text" name="SearchString" /><input type="submit" id="btnSearch" value="Filter" />
    <input type="button" id="btnDisableFilteredList" value="Disable Filtered List" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the `btnDisableFilteredList` the disabled prop first:

```
disabled="disabled"
```

Then setup an [on click](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event listener on the `btnSearch` input to remove the disabled prop from the `btnDisableFilteredList` input.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#btnSearch").on("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#btnDisableFilteredList").prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-heading">
<form id="frmAutoCritical">        
    Search: <input type="text" name="SearchString" />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSearch"value="Filter"/>
    <input type="button" id="btnDisableFilteredList" value="Disable Filtered List" disabled="disabled"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I agree! But the question specifically asked for a jQuery answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
        $("#btnDisableFilteredList").css("display", "inline-block");
    });
});
```

```css
#btnDisableFilteredList {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-heading">
    <form id="frmAutoCritical">
        Search:
        <input type="text" name="SearchString" />
        <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Filter" />
        <input type="button" id="btnDisableFilteredList" value="Disable Filtered List" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LJQLKz)

I used `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` to avoid reloading the page, then to submit the form you can use [jQuery's AJAX Function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)